# How to make a complex gem in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to make a complex gem for Rails 4, but I don't know how. I only find tutorials for simple gems which for example offer only a simple function.
Is there a tutorial or any other help for the development of a gem which also have models, views and controllers?

Thanks for help!

kagutsuchi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for an [`Engine`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html), provided that you're trying to add functionality to a Rails app.

Isolated engines function like Rails apps, and can be mounted in `config/routes.rb` so that they are accessible.

Traditional engines, examples of which include Clearance and Devise, provide functionality which interacts directly with the host app. These should only be considered in special cases, such as when you will need to share models.